# best way to optimise 3 queries to a single one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Suppose I have the following queries.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM info WHERE info = 'a' and uid = 1
SELECT count(*) FROM info WHERE info = 'b' and uid = 1
SELECT count(*) FROM info WHERE info = 'c' and uid = 1;
```

Instead of writing 3 queries is there any way so that I can get all these details in a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT info, count(*) as info_cnt 
FROM T
WHERE uid = 1 and info IN ('a', 'b','c')
GROUP BY info
```

Comment: this can be simplified more, `WHERE uid = 1 and info IN ('a', 'b','c')`

Answer (score 4):

Group By?

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, info FROM info WHERE uid=1 GROUP BY info

count | info
5       a
10      b
11      c
```

Comment: This query also generates rows with info != a,b,c

Comment: this query has issue when the info is not a or b or c

Comment: then add condition `AND info IN ('a','b','c')`. Who ever said that an Answer on SO needs to be a 100% correct Copy&Paste solution? excluding wrong info-types should not be something to be worried about.

Comment: i understand the query is correct but i just wanted to say that it doesnt solve what i was trying to do

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  info,
        SUM(CASE WHEN info = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `a`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN info = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `b`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN info = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `c`
FROM    tableName
WHERE   uid = 1 AND info IN ('a','b','c')
GROUP   BY info
```

This will give you result in row

```
uid a   b   c
==============
1   5   2   6
```

Comment: The same comment: this query doesn't filter rows with info != a,b,c

Comment: yea it gives all the other ones where info not equal to a,b,c

Comment: @kiba all you need to do is to add `AND info IN ('a','b','c')`

Comment: even though this works but the query time is higher than the other one